# Perl - Logging to terminal from a long running system call

Tags: perl

I am calling an external program from my perl code using backticks

```
print `<some long running program>`
```

The long running program prints detailed log messages onto standard output.
The problem I'm having is that due to buffering, the output from the long running program is printed all at once after it has finished its execution.
I tried making the STDOUT filehandle "hot" but that did not help.

Is there anyway I can have my program print continuously onto the screen?

Comment: The classic perl article, [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) may apply.

Comment: It's useful, but I think the root here is more the backticks than the flushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open as an exec pipe rather than using backticks.

```
open ( my $prog_stdout, "-|", "/your/program" ) or die $!;
```

This will `fork` and `exec` but give you access to `$prog_stdout` to do things with.

E.g.

```
while ( <$prog_stdout> ) { 
    print;
}
```

(It'll close if your external program exits, so the `while` will terminate).

You may also want to include autoflushing of the filehandle. http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html

But that may not be necessary, as output won't be buffered indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be buffering but the fact that back ticks return when external program finishes.
You can however use reading pipe to read external output line by line,

```
use autodie;

open my $pipe, "-|", "<some long running program>";
# $pipe->autoflush();

while (<$pipe>) { .. }
```